# What is $\frac 1 n$ called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, fractions

I have forgotten the name of this, and Google is not helpful (I've even tried searching "1 divided by n" and the answer has not come up).

What is it called when you have a number, $n$, and perform $\dfrac{1}{n}$?

This is a silly question, but I've been trying to recall it's name for about an hour now and cannot remember... thanks!

Comment: Inverse ? Reciprocal ?

Comment: Reciprocal seems right. The reciprocal of a number is the number's multiplicative inverse.

Comment: it is a sequence which has the Limit $0$ for $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Uh... okay...

Comment: @Peter Lmao. I guess someone should mention fractions though.

Comment: Unit fraction is another name.

Comment: I searched the internet and found the answer immediately!   ... Oh hang on, it linked me to this Q&A  :D :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiplicative inverse, or reciprocal.

Comment: THAT'S IT - reciprocal, thanks!

Comment: I find it sad that giving an easy answer just got me 70 reputation points in 6 minutes.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Well, then you should only have posted a comment :)

Comment: You're just racking up more with your comment now.

Comment: @Peter well usually I pend most of my time adding or fixing tags I can figure out are wrong and maybe occasionally a math processing error ( a lot recently using || instead of \| it seems)

Comment: spend * and no comments don't typically wrack anything but usefulness tags, or flags. I have 388 revisions and about 106 answers.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Easy-to-understand answers to easy-to-understand questions always pick up a lot of rep. Think of it as compensation for all those answers you spent a lot of time on and scored +3 because nobody wanted to read something difficult.

Comment: @Peter No! Comments are for requesting clarifications to the question, not for posting short answers.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Anyone can handle this in the way she/he wants. In such cases, I tend to post a comment, sometimes (but not often) I give an answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby is that the reciprocal on this site ? might take me a while to find a new way to gain reputation though I suck at asking questions ( only 7 not deleted, above 2000 you don't get peer reviews so you don't get the +2 each time).

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee If you don't want the rep, you could always make your post a community wiki.